# How can we encode # in URL in Angular 7 and send to back-end server as back-end don't receive anything whatever comes after # in URL

Tags: angular

We are using Angular 7 and we are using `#` location strategy.

Our URL is `https://domain:port/#/something/1248/1`.

We are using pingfederate for SSO with OpenID Connect with Authentication FLow using OAuth2 in backend.

Whatever comes after `#` ie: `/something/1248/1` is not received by the back-end server

But when we tried manually to encode the `#` with `%20` and send, it was received.

We need help how can we achieve same in Angular 7

Answer (score 0):

Angular is a Single Page App - it doesn't make round-trips to the server on URL changes like your standard web page (requesting a new page on every URL change). The hash location strategy is a purely Angular implementation for it handling its own routing and such.

By replacing the # with the % encoding (presumably in the URL bar), you're just telling the browser to literally go to that page - which is browsing *away* from the Angular SPA. The hash encoding is there to *stop* the browser from doing just that and have Angular handle the routing, not the server.

As with standard websites, to make specific round-trips (e.g. for data), you'd do an AJAX call or some such - Angular is the same in that you would make use of its HttpClient to make calls elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply ! , yes we know that, but what we want is just encode the # in URL. Can we encode the # in above URL ?  if yes than we need help to implement that.

Comment: At what point? Where is this URL coming from/going to? You can use the basic JS function to [encode a URL](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) to remove the special characters and replace with their ``%xx`` type. What exactly is the usage for this that you're after?